# Foundation 6 div breaking in large viewport

Tags: html, zurb-foundation-6

In large viewport you can see the header is adding more space on left side
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixvEY.png

I want it to look like this image which is in normal viewport.I want to try and avoid the use of media queries.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYKGt.png

Comment: wonderful. And you now expect us to write the whole thing from scratch? Or is there *anything* which you tried yourself and where you can pinpoint the place you have problems with?

Comment: here is my code for header. https://jsfiddle.net/x3086hyy/  i'm having problem with row.

Comment: Here is my new code with correction.. https://jsfiddle.net/rz0pz41h/

When i turn the resolution in large screen for example  1920px the the text of banner left side goes out of row.. and its shows miss align.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/rz0pz41h/3/

```
.banner-text {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    padding-left: 4em;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-top:1em;
    background-color: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.5);
  width:55%;
}
.banner-text-inner{ position:relative; float: right; width:100%; max-width: 630px; }
```

After some CSS tweaks, seems working fine now.... :)